# Can't login to heroku with mintty

Tags: heroku, cygwin, mingw, mintty

When I run heroku in mintty (tried both mingw and cygwin) it's do nothing, no e-mail promt. But when I run heroku via bash (mingw or cygwin) it's act as expected (ask my heroku credentials). Whats wrong with mintty. Also tried with clear minttyrc config file.

Answer (score 0):

Install `winpty` from `https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/releases/`. Download the tarball, extract it and add to PATH.

then in mintty:

```
winpty heroku.cmd login
```

should work.